# Removed voluntarily from UK six years ago, can I apply for a new visa?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, removal

I was removed voluntarily in 2013 from the UK, can I apply for new UK visitor visa?

From 2013 I have not applied and I will try in 2019.

Comment: Waste of money IMO

Answer (score 2):

Your ban https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf will have expired so you can of course apply for a visa. However, with that UK travel history the likelihood of approval is pretty low (possibly zero).